# Change multiple cell values based on other cell value(s)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to change the cells which contain `moving` to `movingToOpen`or `movingToClose` based on the status given in the next cell(s).

Sometimes the cycle gets interrupted and doesn't move from `open` to `close`  or `close` to `open`

this is my current dataframe:

```
                   DateTime  moving
id                                 
36  2018-11-12 15:06:02.487    open
37  2018-11-12 15:06:03.691  moving
38  2018-11-12 15:06:05.505  moving
39  2018-11-12 15:06:08.622   close
40  2018-11-12 15:06:09.023   close
41  2018-11-12 15:06:09.931   close
42  2018-11-12 15:06:11.944  moving
43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756  moving
44  2018-11-12 15:06:15.168  moving
45  2018-11-12 15:06:18.388   close
46  2018-11-12 15:06:20.100  moving
47  2018-11-12 15:06:23.316  moving
48  2018-11-12 15:06:25.730    open
49  2018-11-12 15:06:26.637    open
50  2018-11-12 15:06:27.644    open
51  2018-11-12 15:06:28.550    open
52  2018-11-12 15:06:28.855    open
53  2018-11-12 15:06:29.356    open
54  2018-11-12 15:06:30.563    open
55  2018-11-12 15:06:31.369  moving
56  2018-11-12 15:06:32.575  moving
57  2018-11-12 15:06:35.593   close
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
                   DateTime  moving
id                                 
36  2018-11-12 15:06:02.487    open
37  2018-11-12 15:06:03.691  movingToClose
38  2018-11-12 15:06:05.505  movingToClose
39  2018-11-12 15:06:08.622   close
40  2018-11-12 15:06:09.023   close
41  2018-11-12 15:06:09.931   close
42  2018-11-12 15:06:11.944  movingToClose
43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756  movingToClose
44  2018-11-12 15:06:15.168  movingToClose
45  2018-11-12 15:06:18.388   close
46  2018-11-12 15:06:20.100  movingToOpen
47  2018-11-12 15:06:23.316  movingToOpen
48  2018-11-12 15:06:25.730    open
49  2018-11-12 15:06:26.637    open
50  2018-11-12 15:06:27.644    open
51  2018-11-12 15:06:28.550    open
52  2018-11-12 15:06:28.855    open
53  2018-11-12 15:06:29.356    open
54  2018-11-12 15:06:30.563    open
55  2018-11-12 15:06:31.369  movingToClose
56  2018-11-12 15:06:32.575  movingToClose
57  2018-11-12 15:06:35.593   close
```

i've tried things where i converted it to numbers and used `np.ediff1d` but that only makes it happen for one row and it seemse to me there is an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `moving` values to `NaN` with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), back filling last non missing values and add to original values filtered by mask:

```
m = df['moving'] == 'moving'
df.loc[m, 'moving'] = 'movingTo' + df['moving'].mask(m).bfill()
print (df)
                   DateTime         moving
36  2018-11-12 15:06:02.487           open
37  2018-11-12 15:06:03.691  movingToclose
38  2018-11-12 15:06:05.505  movingToclose
39  2018-11-12 15:06:08.622          close
40  2018-11-12 15:06:09.023          close
41  2018-11-12 15:06:09.931          close
42  2018-11-12 15:06:11.944  movingToclose
43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756  movingToclose
44  2018-11-12 15:06:15.168  movingToclose
45  2018-11-12 15:06:18.388          close
46  2018-11-12 15:06:20.100   movingToopen
47  2018-11-12 15:06:23.316   movingToopen
48  2018-11-12 15:06:25.730           open
49  2018-11-12 15:06:26.637           open
50  2018-11-12 15:06:27.644           open
51  2018-11-12 15:06:28.550           open
52  2018-11-12 15:06:28.855           open
53  2018-11-12 15:06:29.356           open
54  2018-11-12 15:06:30.563           open
55  2018-11-12 15:06:31.369  movingToclose
56  2018-11-12 15:06:32.575  movingToclose
57  2018-11-12 15:06:35.593          close
```

Comment: The speed with which you solve, it's not for no reason that you have number 1 weekly reputation :)

Comment: @cph_sto - hmmm, also I think main reason is huge python coders in these days, so many question about python/pandas...

Comment: Yes, there are, but it doesn't undermine your skill set indeed :)

Comment: "Can't accept an answer in 6 minutes"
I am amazed you always solve my problems so quickly when i've been stuck on them for so long...

Comment: @jezrael
This works exactly in the way I described my problem, but it seems that I made a mistake in the way i wanted my dataframe to be presented. Should i make a new post? if I edit this dataframe your solution won't work anymore.

Comment: @MartijnvanAmsterdam - Can you create new question?

Comment: @jezrael - I wanted to create the new question, but I then realised that the way i have transformed my data to get this dataframe is wrong. Because it isn't possible to base the movement of the object based on the state it was previously in or the state it is going to be in. 
I'll make a new post now to describe the entiriety of the problem.

Comment: @jezrael - I have the post, but since i got to go now, ill post it tomorrow morning (Europe time)  so i can answer comments.

Comment: @jezrael - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53553444/determining-a-cell-value-based-on-previous-next-cell-values