# Determining a cell value based on previous/next cell value(s)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow-up from a previous post of mine: [Change multiple cell values based on other cell value(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53539078/change-multiple-cell-values-based-on-other-cell-values/53539132?noredirect=1#comment93950476_53539132)

this is what a normal cycle of an object looks like:

```
                   DateTime  limitswitchopen  limitswitchclose  safetyedgeclose  safetyedgeopen  photocells  traploopext  rectloopext         moving                  comment
0   2018-11-12 15:04:46.861                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close                      NaN
1   2018-11-12 15:04:57.149                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close                      NaN
2   2018-11-12 15:05:05.046                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close                  Normaal
3   2018-11-12 15:05:06.859                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen                  Normaal
4   2018-11-12 15:05:10.080                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen                  Normaal
5   2018-11-12 15:05:11.801                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open                  Normaal
6   2018-11-12 15:05:13.409                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open                  Normaal
7   2018-11-12 15:05:17.142                1                 0                0               0           0            1            0           open                  Normaal
8   2018-11-12 15:05:18.754                1                 0                0               0           0            1            0           open                  Normaal
9   2018-11-12 15:05:19.055                1                 0                0               0           0            0            1           open                  Normaal
10  2018-11-12 15:05:19.763                1                 0                0               0           0            0            1           open                  Normaal
11  2018-11-12 15:05:20.367                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open                  Normaal
12  2018-11-12 15:05:21.575                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose                  Normaal
13  2018-11-12 15:05:23.385                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose                  Normaal
14  2018-11-12 15:05:26.505                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close                  Normaal
15  2018-11-12 15:05:26.906                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close                      NaN
```

I need to know in which direction the object is moving. So what i did was

`df['moving] = df[(df.limitswitchclose == 0) & (df.limitswitchopen == 0)]
df['open'] = df[(dfsamen.limitswitchclose == 0) & (df.limitswitchopen == 1)]
df['close'] = df[(dfsamen.limitswitchclose == 1) & (df.limitswitchopen == 0)]`

which I merged into one column and then made the previous post.
and then i used that code to create dataframe above where the direction is shown. Which works in this case. But when the cycle gets interrupted the direction changes based on an interruption during opening/closing.

```
                   DateTime  limitswitchopen  limitswitchclose  safetyedgeclose  safetyedgeopen  photocells  traploopext  rectloopext         moving                  comment
41  2018-11-12 15:06:09.931                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
42  2018-11-12 15:06:11.944                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756                0                 0                0               0           1            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
44  2018-11-12 15:06:15.168                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
45  2018-11-12 15:06:18.388                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
46  2018-11-12 15:06:20.100                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
47  2018-11-12 15:06:23.316                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
48  2018-11-12 15:06:25.730                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
49  2018-11-12 15:06:26.637                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
50  2018-11-12 15:06:27.644                1                 0                0               0           0            1            0           open             Fotocellopen
51  2018-11-12 15:06:28.550                1                 0                0               0           0            1            1           open             Fotocellopen
52  2018-11-12 15:06:28.855                1                 0                0               0           0            0            1           open             Fotocellopen
53  2018-11-12 15:06:29.356                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
54  2018-11-12 15:06:30.563                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
55  2018-11-12 15:06:31.369                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
56  2018-11-12 15:06:32.575                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
57  2018-11-12 15:06:35.593                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
```

at `43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756` `photocells = 1` this will make the object close and then start to open again.

So what this dataframe should be is:

```
                   DateTime  limitswitchopen  limitswitchclose  safetyedgeclose  safetyedgeopen  photocells  traploopext  rectloopext         moving                  comment
41  2018-11-12 15:06:09.931                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
42  2018-11-12 15:06:11.944                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
43  2018-11-12 15:06:13.756                0                 0                0               0           1            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
44  2018-11-12 15:06:15.168                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
45  2018-11-12 15:06:18.388                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
46  2018-11-12 15:06:20.100                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
47  2018-11-12 15:06:23.316                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0   movingToopen             Fotocellopen
48  2018-11-12 15:06:25.730                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
49  2018-11-12 15:06:26.637                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
50  2018-11-12 15:06:27.644                1                 0                0               0           0            1            0           open             Fotocellopen
51  2018-11-12 15:06:28.550                1                 0                0               0           0            1            1           open             Fotocellopen
52  2018-11-12 15:06:28.855                1                 0                0               0           0            0            1           open             Fotocellopen
53  2018-11-12 15:06:29.356                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
54  2018-11-12 15:06:30.563                1                 0                0               0           0            0            0           open             Fotocellopen
55  2018-11-12 15:06:31.369                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
56  2018-11-12 15:06:32.575                0                 0                0               0           0            0            0  movingToclose             Fotocellopen
57  2018-11-12 15:06:35.593                0                 1                0               0           0            0            0          close             Fotocellopen
```

So what i need is a way to determine whether the object is opening or closing. 
If limitswitchclose goes from `1` to `0` it will always be opening and if limitswitchopen goes from `1` to `0` it will always be closing. But based on the other columns in df it can change direction. If `safetyedgeopen = 1` during opening it will close again. But if `traploopext = 1` during opening it will continue opening.

How do i tackle this problem?

(I'll continue trying to solve it and post my answer if it works, I can give more examples of how I want the dataframe to look but the post was getting long)

Comment: Please remove the columns that are unnecessary for the question you have. I count at least 5 columns in your example `DataFrame` that are not necessary to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you mainly ask, it's "how do I assign a value based on the value of previous row." The way I Would do this is to simply shift the filtering condition by one row. I won't give the solution for all the options, but you can just expand the filtering condition appropriately.

this line of code filters by where the neighbouring row would have the value of 1 in photocells, and if that's the case, then replaces the current rows "tomoving" to "toclosing", or "toclosing", to "tomoving"

`df.loc[df.shift(1).photocells==1,'moving'] = df.loc[df.shift(1).photocells==1,'moving'].str.replace('Toclose','To_open').str.replace('Toopen','To_close').str.replace('_','')`

Comment: Is it possible to add more condtions to the df shift? for example

`df.loc[df.shift(1).photocells==1,'moving', dfshift(1).moving=='close', 'moving'] = df.loc[df.shift(1).photocells==1,'moving'].str.replace('Toclose','To_open').str.replace('Toopen','To_close').str.replace('_','')`

Comment: You mean you want photocells==1 as well as moving=='close'? In that case you can add more filters by using `&` note that each statement needs to be within `()` e.g. `df.loc[(df.condition1) & (df.condition2),'moving']` in this case you can assign the condition to a variable so `filtering = (df.shift(1).photocells==1) & (df.shift(1).moving=='close')` then filter by it: `df.loc[filtering,'moving'] = df.loc[filtering,'moving'].str.replace('Toclose','To_open').str.replace('Toopen','To_close').str.replace('_','')`